# One AutoreleasePool per object?

Tags: c++, objective-c++, nsautoreleasepool

I can't have a "big" `NSAutoreleasePool` in `main()` – I'm not allowed to touch it. So what's about having one pool per object?

```
struct MacGuiEngine
{
  // members …

  ScopedAutoreleasePool pool;
};

struct MacFontEngine
{
  // members …

  ScopedAutoreleasePool pool;
};
```

Is this a valid "pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you can't touch `main()`, when do you call `UIApplicationMain()`? I'm assuming this is iOS, since you don't need to create an autorelease pool in `main()` on Mac. Wherever you call `UIApplicationMain()` is where you want the top-level autorelease pool.

Remember, an autorelease pool is automatically created for you for each event loop, so you generally don't need to create one. My initial experiments are that removing it from `main()` on iPad at least didn't cause any leaks. You can find out by setting a breakpoint on `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool()`. The only concern would be methods called prior to the event loop. I believe if the application delegate is generated programmatically, then its `-init` may be called prior to an event loop. But even making autoreleased objects in app delegate's `+initialize` didn't cause any leaks for me.

If there are any places you need an autorelease pool (where `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool()` gets called and you see something like "object autoreleased without pool -- just leaking"), then you just need to create a pool in that method:

```
- (id)someMethod {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ....
    id result = ....

    [pool drain];
    return result;
}
```

But I'm still a little at a loss of how you're starting your main runloop, but can't create an autorelease pool.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have told you more details. I'm working on Mac, not iOS. And I have my own event loop, where I can create a NSAutoreleasePool. But MacFontEngine will be used before I call `MacEventLoop::run()` (MacEventLoop is my own event loop). That's the way I came to the idea, that MacGuiEngine, MacFontEngine etc. should keep there one autorelease pool.

Comment: OK, so you're building a C++ wrapper around Cocoa I'm guessing? Yeah, I've built one of those, too.... There is no sensible way to give each object its own autoreleasepool. Pools live on a stack and there is only one active globally at any time for a given thread, and they need to be destroyed regularly to free memory. When calling from C++ into ObjC, it is very common to have to wrap your public (callable from C++) methods as I show above in `someMethod`. Be sure to read the docs on `NSAutoreleasePool`. It explains a lot of it.